# Reduce the width of card-header in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a card-layout in my page where I want to reduce the width of the card-header of the bootstrap card-layout.

I tried using the margin property for but it reduces but not the whole div, it changes the value inside the card-header div.

```
<div class="card card-nav-tabs text-center grid-selection">
          <div class="card-body custom-card-body">
            <h5 class="card-text">ARCADE</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted custom-game-subtitle" id="arcade">

            <div class="custom-subtitle-text">
              Learn the Synonyms while you play.
            </div>
            <div class="custom-loading-svg" style="display:none">
              <img src="img/loading.svg">
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- </a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to reduce the whole div of the card-header?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/118716/)

Comment: can you upload an image of your requirement? what do you exactly want it's not clear.

Comment: I just want to reduce the header width not the whole card @rajibkarmaker

Comment: Why doesn't the snippet actually use `card-header`?

Comment: Even if I use card-header, it does not work. Please check the updated JSFiddle. @ZimSystem

Comment: I'm not seeing card-header in the fiddle either.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own style rules to a Bootstrap element, Just make sure you put the Bootstrap style first in and then your own custom style in the header of your HTML.

You could also use this:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that may help.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your html structure. Check out the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/118712/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <div class="custom-card-body" style="width: 30%; background: red; margin: auto">
            <h5 class="card-text">ARCADE</h5>
     </div>

      <div class="card card-body card-nav-tabs text-center grid-selection">
          <div class="card-footer text-muted custom-game-subtitle" id="arcade">

            <div class="custom-subtitle-text">
              Learn the Synonyms while you play.
            </div>
            <div class="custom-loading-svg" style="display:none">
              <img src="img/loading.svg">
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- </a> -->
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to reduce the width of the card-header alone not card-body

Comment: Do you mean the width of the box with ARCADE??

Comment: Yes only the div which has ARCADE

Comment: I just edited my post you check my edited post with new fiddle

Comment: You have to change your html structure. Check out the updated fiddle